# In a C++ map, is there any way to search for the key given a value?

Tags: c++

In a C++ `std::map`, is there any way to search for the key given the mapped value? Example:

I have this map:

```
map<int,string> myMap;
myMap[0] = "foo";
```

Is there any way that I can find the corresponding `int`, given the value `"foo"`?

```
cout << myMap.some_function("foo") <<endl;

Output: 0
```

Comment: Only via iterating through.

Comment: No not really. Have another map going the other way and keep the two in sync

Comment: You might be interested in [Boost.Bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::map` doesn't provide a (fast) way to find the key of a given value.

What you want is often called a "bijective map", or short "bimap". [Boost has such a data structure.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) This is typically implemented by using two index trees "glued" together (where `std::map` has only one for the keys). [Boost also provides the more general *multi* index with similar use cases.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html)

If you don't want to use Boost, if storage is not a big problem, and if you can affort the extra code effort, you can simply use two maps and glue them together manually:

```
std::map<int, string> myMapForward;
std::map<string, int> myMapBackward;    // maybe even std::set

// insertion becomes:
myMapForward.insert(std::make_pair(0, "foo"));
myMapBackward.insert(std::make_pair("foo", 0));

// forward lookup becomes:
myMapForwar[0];

// backward lookup becomes:
myMapBackward["foo"];
```

Of course you can wrap those two maps in a class and provide some useful interface, but this might be a bit overkill, and using two maps with the same content is not an optional solution anyways. As commented below, exception safety is also a problem of this solution. But in many applications it's already enough to simply add another reverse map.

Please note that since `std::map` stores *unique keys*, this approach will support backward lookup only for *unique values*, as collisions in the value space of the forward map correspond to collisions in the key space of the backward map.

Comment: If you want strong exception safety then you need to undo the first insert when the second one fails. Memory usage and locality here is not ideal. In this light I would recommend boost multi-index.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin You're right. The second half of my answers only provides a *quick and dirty* solution with some flaws for coders with Boost allergy, which seems to be pretty common.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin But thanks for pointing this out. I added a hint in my answer.

Comment: It's been a number of years since I last encountered boost aversion. Or may be I was careful to find a job where anything goes as long as it is correct and fast enough. Anyway, I find boost multi-index library to be one of the most useful in boost.

Comment: Just to mention that if you have non-unique values, you can use std::multimap<string,int> myMapBackward.

Comment: @nbilal Right, but then the lookup code expands to something like `find` or `equal_range`, depending on the requirements. If the data is bijective, two `map`s are fine.

Answer (score 2):

No, not directly.

One option is to examine each value in the map until you find what you are looking for.  This, obviously, will be O(n).

In order to do this you could just write a `for()` loop, or you could use `std::find_if()`.  In order to use `find_if()`, you'll need to create a predicate.  In C++11, this might be a lambda:

```
typedef std::map <unsigned, Student> MyMap;
MyMap myMap; 

// ...

const string targetName = "Jones";
find_if (myMap.begin(), myMap.end(), [&targetName] (const MyMap::value_type& test)
{
  if (test.second.mName == targetName)
    return true;
});
```

If you're using C++03, then this could be a functor:

```
struct MatchName
: public std::unary_function <bool, MyMap::value_type>
{
  MatchName (const std::string& target) : mTarget (target) {}
  bool operator() (const MyMap::value_type& test) const
  {
    if (test.second.mName == mTarget)
      return true;
    return false;
  }
private:
  const std::string mTarget;
};


// ...

find_if (myMap.begin(), myMap.end(), MatchName (target));
```

Another option is to build an index.  The index would likely be another map, where the key is whatever values you want to find and the value is some kind of index back to the main map.

Suppose your main map contains `Student` objects which consist of a name and some other stuff, and the key in this map is the Student ID, an integer.  If you want to find the student with a particular last name, you could build an indexing map where the key is a last name (probably want to use `multimap` here), and the value is the student ID.  You can then index back in to the main map to get the remainder of the `Student`'s attributes.

There are challenges with the second approach.  You must keep the main map and the index (or indicies) synchronized when you add or remove elements.  You must make sure the index you choose as the value in the index is not something that may change, like a pointer.  If you are multithreading, then you have to give a think to how both the map and index will be protected without introducing deadlocks or race conditions.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to accomplish this that I can think of is to iterate through it. This is most likely not what you want, but it's the best shot I can think of. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by *iterating* which will take `O(n) time`. Or you can *store the reverse map* which will take `O(n) space`.

By iterating:

```
std::map<int, string> fmap;

for (std::map<int,string>::iterator it=fmap.begin(); it!=fmap.end(); ++it)
    if (strcmp(it->second,"foo"))
        break;
```

By storing reverse map:

```
std::map<int, string> fmap;
std::map<string, int> bmap;

fmap.insert(std::make_pair(0, "foo"));
bmap.insert(std::make_pair("foo", 0));

fmap[0]; // original map lookup

bmap["foo"]; //reverse map lookup
```

Answer (score 0):

No, You can not do this. You simply have to iterate over map and match each value with the item to be matched and return the corresponding key and it will cost you high time complexity equal to O(n).